# Issue while running spring ; No error logs

Tags: spring

I am a new bee to spring and am writing my first spring program.I have the following files.

```
package com.springstarter;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class SpringUser
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        SpringStarter starter = ( SpringStarter ) context.getBean( "springstarter" );
        starter.getMessage();
    }
}
```

I have a bean called SpringStarter

```
package com.springstarter;

public class SpringStarter
{
    private String message;

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage( String message )
    {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="springstarter" class="com.springstarter.SpringStarter">
       <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

The following is the package structure:

[image]

I have run the program in eclipse Mars, using Spring 4.2.4.
I didn't find any compilation issues, but the program is just showing the following logs.

```
Jan 14, 2016 10:36:08 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@73a83205: startup date [Thu Jan 14 10:36:08 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 14, 2016 10:36:08 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
```

The expected output though, is Hello World!

Kindly let me know if i'm making any obvious mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong, but to print the output on console, so you should use it like:

```
System.out.println(starter.getMessage());
```

Comment: Thanks!. I knew it was something petty.